# API Call - Protecting Bearer Tokens & API Keys

Tags: c#

I am writing an C# application (windows form) where the application calls multiple APIs that are authenticated using an API key or Bearer Tokens. I am using HttpClient.

One API uses an API Key and API username to GET a Bear Token. Where should I store the Bearer Token that is returned and for security reasons it should not be in plain text. Also, should I call for a new bearer token each time I open the API application or call and save it and only call a new once the bear token expires (e.g. in 7 days)?

Other APIs use API Keys and API Subscription Keys that do not expire. Where should I store these keys so that they are not in plain text in my code, Can these be stored safely (e.g. encrypted).

Thanks, Greg

Comment: You can encrypt them and that will deter most basic users. However, keep in mind that if users have the application, they can reverse engineer it and obtain the actual source code, they can also dump the program's memory while it's running to see the decrypted values, as well as other attack vectors. All in all, there's pretty much nothing you can do, which is why that deployment method is called "public applications" and cannot be trusted from your back-ends.

Comment: So when an API key is required is just stored in plain text in the code? I thought it might be possible to store it somewhere in the application where it would be encrypted securely

Comment: You *can* encrypt it, using AES/RSA or whatever you want. It just adds very little security

Comment: The bearer tokens are secure enough without being stored in encrypted form. Only the API or the server can create a bearer token, but anyone can read it. After that, the user is responsible for his device and his data.
You can try secure the tokens but like @CamiloTerevinto
 sayd - "It just adds very little security"

Comment: I have encrypted the access codes using AES but the key to decrypt the code will need to be in my code somewhere. I was hoping it could be stored somewhere where it is not visible as such.